# Find the original file extension?

Tags: avi

I have changed the file extension in order to hide them (such as .avi or .mp4 to .stg) and forgotten the original extension, how to check the original extension and reconvert them?

Comment: What are you playing these files with?  It probably doesn't matter, change it to something the media player will open, and it will likely figure it out.  A media player doesn't use the extension to determine what codecs it needs.

Comment: I'm more puzzled by the original premise… why change the extension in the first place? Perfect example of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: If you do that, always *add*, never replace: `filename.avi` becomes `filename.avi.renamed`. I sometimes use this trick for folders that I think can be removed from my system (e.g. they seem leftovers from installations), but I'm not 100% sure about. If something fails after the rename, I can just rename back.

Comment: As you can see from the answers, [edit] your question and add an OS tag.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux and OSX there is a command

```
file yourfilename
```

that guesses the file type.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable programming in almost any language, you could write a script and just examine the first few bytes of the files headers and rename as appropriate.  Most all video/picture/audio headers are available online.

Comment: Would be nice to know, where online they are available.  Also, I do not see why a script is more preferred over a hex editor.

Comment: Just search using your favorite search site.  "AVI header format...".  Some are on Microsoft's site, others are on various graphic editors sites.  As to why a script is preferred - you indicated you changed the file extensions - but didn't specify how many.  One or two, go ahead with an editor.  Thousands - tens of thousands - would take you months to do it with an editor.

Answer (score 0):

[Trid](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) is a useful command line application that identifies a ton of filetypes. Assuming it actually is a file, it should help identify it.

It uses a slightly different strategy from file, and might detect *possible* filetypes rather than what the magic number of the file says

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file in a HEX editor like HxD you will be able to see the file header on the right hand side, This will give you information about your file type.